# c# Generic Service Casting & Implementation issues

Tags: c#, generics, service, implementation

I have a simple question (I hope) which I can't find an answer anywhere. I want to implement a generic (a little bit complicated) service.
Github repo: https://github.com/arnoldsimha/genericRepo-issue 
This is my generic Interface:

```
public interface IContactsService<T> where T : Contact
{
    Task<T> GetContact(string email);
}
```

This is the contact:

```
 public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Now I've created a new Service that needs to implement this interface.
I've extended Contact:

```
public class AppContact : Contact
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

And service:

```
public class MyNewContactService<T> : IContactsService<AppContact>
{
    public async Task<AppContact> GetContact(string email)
    {

    }
}
```

This is how I register it:

```
services.AddScoped<IContactsService<AppContact>, MyNewContactService<AppContact>>();
```

So far so good. I've created another service that implements the same interface. May I ask why when I'm trying to cast MyNewContactService as IContactsService I'm getting null?

```
myNewContactService as IContactsService<AppContact>
```

I'm trying to add an option to select the implementation according to a specific condition.

Thank you

Comment: show us how do you get `myNewContactService` so we can see that it's an instance of `MyNewContactService<T>`

Comment: Also, please check your posted code. There is no implementation for `IContcatsService<T>.GetContact(..)` in your `MyNewContactService<T>`

Comment: I guess, that you should make `MyNewContactService<T>` non generic, e.g remove `T` type parameter. It isn't clear, why do you need it, because it already implements `IContcatsService<AppContact>` interface

Comment: I've updated the thread with service registration and proper name. @PavelAnikhouski Event when I remove it and register this way: services.AddScoped<IContcatsService<AppContact>, MyNewContactService(); it's still return null on casting

Comment: Why do you need to perform this registration `services.AddScoped<IContcatsService<AppContact>, MyNewContactService<AppContact>>();` Maybe just `services.AddScoped<IContcatsService<AppContact>, MyNewContactService>();`, without type argument?

Comment: You commented before I managed to update the comment :) Even with this change I'm still getting: Cannot implicitly convert type 'IContcatsService<AppContact>' to 'IContcatsService<Contact>'

Comment: ICont**cats**Service ?

Comment: @vasily.sib I fixed the text, It's doesn't fix the issue:(

Comment: I guess you have some gramatic error somewhere in your code, cuz that code that you provide is 100% working. We need a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get further.

Comment: @vasily.sib the fail on casting and not NONexisting class. I will create blank project on github and share here

Comment: @vasily.sib please see demo repo: https://github.com/arnoldsimha/genericRepo-issue .if you run home controller you will get the error